# Using MongoDB 3.4 to load and save userdata

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous

How can I find a document and retrieve it if found, but insert and retrieve it if not found in one command?

I have an outline for the formats I wish my documents to look like for a user's data. Here is what it looks like

```
{
  "username": "HeyAwesomePeople",
  "uuid": "0f91ede5-54ed-495c-aa8c-d87bf405d2bb",
  "global": {},
  "servers": {}
}
```

When a user first logs in, I want to store the first two values of data (username and uuid) and create those empty values (global and servers.  Both those global and servers will later on have more information filled into them, but for now they can be blank). But I also don't want to override any data if it already exists for the user.

I would normally use the insertOne or updateOne calls to the collection and then use the upsert (new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)) option to insert if it isn't found but in this case I also need to retrieve the user's document aswell.

So in a case in which the user isn't found in the database, I need to insert the outlined data into the database and return the document saved. In a case where the user is found in the database, I need to just return the document from the database.

How would I go about doing this? I am using the latest version of Mongo which has deprecated the old BasicDBObject types, so I can't find many places online that use the new 'Document' type. Also, I am using the Async driver for java and would like to keep the calls to the minimum.

Comment: What is your filter criteria ? How do you check for the record before inserting new one ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find a document and retrieve it if found, but insert and retrieve it if not found in one command?

You can use [findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) method to find and update/upsert.

The MongoDB Java driver exposes the same method name [findOneAndUpdate()](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#findOneAndUpdate-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.client.model.FindOneAndUpdateOptions-). For example:

```
// Example callback method for Async
SingleResultCallback<Document> printDocument = new SingleResultCallback<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(final Document document, final Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(document.toJson());
    }
};


Document userdata = new Document("username","HeyAwesomePeople")
                       .append("uuid", "0f91ede5")
                       .append("global", new Document())
                       .append("servers", new Document());


collection.findOneAndUpdate(userdata,
                            new Document("$set", userdata), 
                            new FindOneAndUpdateOptions()
                                .upsert(true)
                                .returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER),
                            printDocument);
```

The query above will try to find a document matching `userdata`; if found set it to the same value as `userdata`. If not found, the `upsert` boolean flag will insert it into the collection. The [returnDocument](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/model/ReturnDocument.html) option is to return the document after the action is performed.

The *upsert* and *returnDocument* flags are part of [FindOneAndUpdateOptions](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/model/FindOneAndUpdateOptions.html#FindOneAndUpdateOptions--)

See also [MongoDB Async Java Driver v3.4](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver-async/) for tutorials/examples. The above snippet was tested with current version of [MongoDB v3.4.x](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community).